# How to loop another loop in python

Tags: python

I wanted to add in list years from 0000 to 9999, what I did:

```
i = 0
a = []

while i <= 9:
    a += [i]
    i += 1
years = []
for i1 in a: 
    for i2 in a:
        for i3 in a:
            for i4 in a:
                numbers = f'{i1}{i2}{i3}{i4}'
                years += [numbers]
```

But what if I need do this 99 times? Is exist any way to do this without simple copypasting code?

Comment: Do you simply want a list with numbers from 0000 to 9999 in it times 99 ?

Comment: @rite2hhh yes, as an example

Comment: Then, you should use the most rudimentary principles in python, and do this-
python3: `["{:04}".format(i) for i in range(10000)]`, It will create a list of list with numbers represented as strings from 0000 to 9999. if you want 99 such lists, there's may ways to do it. One of them is to create a list of lists.
`[["{:04}".format(i) for i in range(10000)] for i in range(99)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a *cartesian product.

```
from itertools import product

for numbers in product([1,2,3], repeat=5): ...
```

However, this increases exponentially with the number of loops, and you should probably rethink what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the `zfill` function  to fill the rest of the left portion with zeros for a string . for `n = 2` it prints from `00` to `99` which is shown below and for `n = 4` it produces the same output as your program.

```
output = []
n=2
for i in xrange(0,10**n):
    output.append(str(i).zfill(n))
print(output)
```

OUTPUT

```
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99']
```